# Determining minimum and maximum lengths of possible regex matches?

Tags: c#, regex

How might I go about analyzing a regular expression to determine the minimum and maximum lengths a matching string can produce? Is there functionality already in the .NET Framework or elsewhere that does this? I can limit the maximum number of characters in the UI, but I'd like to provide proper values in error text for the user as well as do reliable string length bounds checks based on the regex before letting RegEx.IsMatch take a stab at it.

```
int RegExMinLength(string regex)
{
   //How do I determine this value?
}
int RegExMaxLength(string regex)
{
   //How do I determine this value?
}
void DoStuff()
{
    var sampleBarcode = "MAT-012345-6789012";
    var regex = "^(?:MAT)(?:-)(?:\d{6})(?:-)(?:\d{6,7})$";
    if (sampleBarcode.Length < RegExMinLength(regex))
        MessageBox.Show($"Barcode string must be of at least {RegExMinLength(regex)} characters in length.");

    if (sampleBarcode.Length <= RegExMaxLength(regex))
        DoOtherStuff(sampleBarcode, RegEx.IsMatch(sampleBarcode, regex, RegexOptions.Singleline, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)));
    else
        throw new StringTooLongException(RegExMaxLength(regex),nameof(sampleBarcode));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Evaluate it and check the results ?

Comment: If they have any "any number of elements can go here" syntax, the maximum would be "infinite", string.MaxLenght or the like. This sounds like the ideal premise for a XY Problem. What are you trying to fix with this?

Comment: Many, if not most regexes don't have any such limits. What are you going to do when there is no max length? `-1`? What about if the length is less than infinite, but larger than an integer?

Comment: @Aybe How would that help? The purpose is to avoid evaluating the regex if the input string (sampleBarcode, in my example) falls outside the bounds, and to provide real bounds values, not estimates.

Comment: Not exactly, but you can use an [online regex visualizer](https://regexper.com/) to make it easier to determine yourself.

Comment: @Geoff this is just a suggestion and not an answer by any means.

Comment: This really isn't a good idea

Comment: @DetectivePikachu Care to expand on that terse statement?

Comment: How could you do with: `^\w+?[.,]+$`? Your request is unanswerable for all regexes.

Comment: @Toto  Well I assume ^\w+?[.,]+$

Your regex has a minimum of 2 character and a maximum of infinite.  
He just needs to change his code to deal with this concept.

I do have the same ask as him  but for different reasons  I need match a string to over 1000 regex. I dont need to try when the length is impossible.